# I'm trying to add validation interaction to this style but it can't find the property. Whats wrong here?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I added styling to my combobox from the ToggleBox control and it all works fine.

But now I want to add extra interaction for when `Validation.HasError` is true.
For some reason it tells me "'Validation' property not found on 'object' ''ExtendedComboBoxControl'" which is my custom control which inherits from ComboBox.

I tried just using triggers in the styling for the combobox directly, but for some reason I can change the border thickness from there but not the background or border brush.

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border x:Name="templateRoot"
                        Background="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border x:Name="splitBorder"
                            Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"
                            Margin="1"
                            Padding="0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            BorderBrush="Transparent"
                            BorderThickness="2,0,0,0"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Path x:Name="arrow"
                              Margin="0"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              Data="F1 M 0,0 L 5,5 L 10,0 L 0,0"
                              Fill="{StaticResource Grey500Brush}" />
                    </Border>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Validation.HasError, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Background}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Border}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource Border.Thickness.Thick}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="splitBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0" />

                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

This isn't the final interaction I wanted to implement, but I expected this to make the combobox background and border brush to turn green when I hover over them while there is a validation error.

Instead it tells me it cant even find the property on my control.

Comment: Are you styling a ComboBox, or a ToggleButton? What property can't it find?

Comment: I used a ControlTemplate with a ToggleButton to add styling to my ComboBox like proposed in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42205538/c-sharp-wpf-borderbrush-wont-set-color . It cant find the property Validation on my ComboBox

Comment: Im styling a ToggleButton, with ComboBox as its ancestor. That structure has worked fine for other properties of the ComboBox like IsEditable, but it cannot find the property Validation in my ComboBox. It correctly looks for the property in the ComboBox.

Comment: Neither ComboBox nor ToggleButton have a Validation property. `Validation` is the name of a class which owns some attached properties.

Comment: but i can use the Validation.HasError in a trigger in the styling of controls. why doesn't this work? and how can i make it work?

Comment: Try `{Binding (Validation.HasError), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}` -- `Binding` thinks `Validation.HasError` is a path to a property of a property. If you add the parens, it understands that `(Validation.HasError)` is a single, two-part name of an attached property. This is one of those little landmines in WPF that makes sense *after* it takes your foot off.

Comment: thank you! this worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ed Plunkett pointed out all i needed to do is change

`<Condition Binding="{Binding Validation.HasError, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false" />`

to

`<Condition Binding="{Binding (Validation.HasError), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false" />`